# SyntaxError al inentar importar la libreria de discord

Tags: python, python-import

estoy intentando hacer un bot de discord y me falla el import de la primera línea no sé por qué.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

Cliente = discord.Client()
cliente = commands.Bot("!")

#Ping al bot
@discord.client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!Hi'):
        await discord.client.send_message(message)
    pass
cliente.run('NTA3Njc5Nzc2OTc1MzU1OTI3.Dr2rZA.Kt5qjj7kBKundrrjDy8pGP_Tsmg')
```

Y me da este error:

```
/usr/bin/python3 /home/mario/PycharmProjects/Bot/Main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mario/PycharmProjects/Bot/Main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import discord
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .state import ConnectionState
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/state.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import utils, compat
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/compat.py", line 32
    create_task = asyncio.async
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

He leido que a veces pasando a la version anterior de python se solucionaba, lo he hecho y no me ha funcionado. 
Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Creo que tienes que instalar asyncio

Comment: Ya lo tengo instalado :S

Answer (score 1):

Esta biblioteca no soporta 3.7. Este error en particular se debe a que async se convierte en una palabra clave reservada. Intenta actualizar la biblioteca.

[Referencia](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1249)